# Setting multiple key/value pairs for NSMutabledictionary in NSURLSession repsonse block

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using NSURLSession to make multiple asynchronous requests to my server with following code:

```
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    ...
    [self.dict setObject:some_obj forKey:some_key];

}] resume];
```

Inside the response block I'm setting key/value pairs for an mutable Dictionary.

My question is:
As the requests are asynchronous, can it be, that theoretically my program tries to set key/value pairs for the dictionary at the same time? An if this is possible, what will happen?

1. Does the app crash?
2. Will be certain key/value pairs not set?
3. Or will it work, as one key/value setting will wait for the other to finish?

If 3. is not the case, what can I do to make 3) work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSMutableDictionary is not documented as thread-safe, so it almost certainly isn't.

However, the [Apple docs on NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSession/) say:

> The completion handler to call when the load request is complete. This handler is executed on the delegate queue.

You (may) pass the delegate queue at session creation, the docs say:

> An operation queue for scheduling the delegate calls and completion handlers. The queue need not be a serial queue. If nil, the session creates a serial operation queue for performing all delegate method calls and completion handler calls.

So as far as setting the keys, if you don't explicitly create the session with a parallel queue you should be fine.  If you did, then you'll need to synchronize access. The easiest way is an `@synchronized` block:

```
@synchronized (self.dict) {
    self.dict[key] = value;
}
```

Depending on when and where you're reading the values, you may need the synchronized block anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I declared an (nonatomic, assign) int counter property in the interface of my class. In the completion handler block, I decrease the counter property with self.counter--. Do I need a `@synchronized{self.counter--}` for the int counter property too?